# How to print javascript return value without clicking a button?

Tags: javascript

I want to print the followers in my webpage, it shows up in the console, but not the html document.
the code:

```
async function getFollowers(user) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://scratchdb.lefty.one/v3/user/info/${user}`);
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      const count = document.getElementById.innerHTML("123");
      count = responseJson.statistics.followers;
      return count;}

function pfollows(user) {
   const element = document.getElementById.innerHTML("123");
   const USER = user;
   getFollowers(USER).then(count => {
      element.textContent = `${USER} has ${count} followers right now.`;
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML code?

Comment: Meanwhile, I can already tell that  `document.getElementById.innerHTML("123")` is not valid. See on MDN how `getElementById` works and also `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById.innerHTML("123")` seems wrong.

You should be passing an id as a string to `document.getElementById` like `document.getElementById("someIdHere")`.  `innerHTML` is not a function and shouldn't have parentheses or an argument after it.

`count` looks like it should be extracted from `responseJson` and returned.

`pfollows` looks like it might be responsible for updating the actual DOM.

Redefining `user` as `USER` is somewhat redundant.

```
async function getFollowers(user) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://scratchdb.lefty.one/v3/user/info/${user}`);
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      const count = responseJson.statistics.followers;
      return count;
}

function pfollows(user) {
   const element = document.getElementById("123").innerHTML;
   getFollowers(user).then(count => {
      element.textContent = `${user} has ${count} followers right now.`;
   });
}
```

When `pfollows` is called, then the element with `id="123"` should have its content set to the desired string.  If `pfollows()` is not called, then nothing will happen.

There's a few more possible touchups to clean up:

- `responseJson` can probably be a `const`
- You can inline return `count` without saving it to a variable `return responseJson.statistics.followers`

but trying to keep the changes minimal as needed to fix the problems.